# Fail2ban filter for a specific string in *access.log

Tags: apache, filter, fail2ban

I have many GET Request on my server to "`nike-air`" URLs like this

```
216.*.*.* - - [13/Dec/2016:20:07:54 +0100] "GET /jd/nike-huarache-2010.php HTTP/1.1" 404
216.*.*.* - - [13/Dec/2016:20:07:57 +0100] "GET /jd/nike-roshe-run-homme-original.php HTTP/1.1" 404
187.*.*.* - - [13/Dec/2016:20:17:26 +0100] "GET /jd/nike-mercurial.php HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I decide to create a fail2ban filter for stop it:

```
# apache-nike.conf
[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"GET .*nike-.*".*
ignoreregex =
```

It works but I think it can be improved? Too bad there is no online tool to create filters :)

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Will this really help? Consider that this looks like a distributed attack. If you indeed want to ban a single IP that way, then why not kick out any address creating more than a few 404s in a given time?

Comment: I already have a filter for 404 but I want to manage them separately